# Prove that for every $g$ meromorphic there exists an entire function $f$ such that $f(z)\neq g(z)$ for all $z$ in $\mathbb C $

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that for every $g$ meromorphic there exists an entire function $f$ such that 
$f(z)\neq g(z)$ for all $z$ in $\mathbb C $.

This problem is in pg 137 in Classical Topics in Complex function theory,Remmert.

the hint given was to see $g$ as $g=f_1/f_2$ where $f_1,f_2$ are entire functions since ring of meromorphic functions is the  quotient field ring of entire  functions.

Further to take $f_1,f_2$ relatively prime so that there exists entire functions $u,v$ such that $u f_1 +vf_2=1$.
I am not able to take the hint forward.